# Asp.net Webpart Manager Connection String Encryption

Tags: encryption, web-parts, connection-string

I am using personalization in my asp.net application. Personalization uses a connection string that it specifies in the web.config file.

Now My ConnectionStrings Section is protected and hence encrypted.

Everything else works fine without a single line of code to decrypt the connection string. But my Webpart Manager fails.

Somehow it is not able to decrypt the connection string. Now is there anywhere in the configuration manager or code that I can tell the Webpart Manager that the connection string is encrypted and that it needs to be decrypted using x encryption provider?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the answer to this question.

I was encrypting the connection string programmatically at runtime if it was not already encrypted.

We are three developers writing code. It was not running because I was encrypting it on my machine and checking it in and then the other developers couldn't decrypt it. It turns out it uses a machine specific key to encrypt it and can be decrypted only on that machine.

So if I keep a decrypted connection string in my web.config and run the code all the webparts will load correctly and everything because it would encrypt it at runtime on my machine and hence be able to decrypt it as well.

This problem won't arise in production because we will deploy the encryption code along with the un-encrypted web.config and then run the code. Once encrypted there, it will be able to decrypt it.

Thanks anyways...